# Access denied when view quiz question by itself

Tags: 7, quiz

If a user tries to access a quiz question, they get an `access denied` message because I have configured the permissions so that users can't view questions outside of the quiz. Is there a way they can be redirected to the beginning of the quiz or for me to change it so they don't just get an "ugly" access denied error?

Comment: I think you might like the [Rabbit Hole module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole). (As long as your questions are nodes)

Comment: which release of Quiz are you using? And what is the path of such questions?

Comment: The latest one and node/qid/take/questionnumber